# Audio tag not playing local file - jQuery mobile App

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am using Dreamweaver cs5.5 for jQuery mobile app and I can stream audio file but local files are not playing,

```
<audio style="max-width:100%" id="demo" controls="controls">
 <source src="audio/Itna Mein Chahon Tumhein.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
       </audio>
```

Comment: Try removing the spaces from the file name.

Comment: if you don't want to rename the sound files put (%20) where the space is without the brackets

Comment: still same problem :( , Play pause button is enable but not playing the file